# In a random binary sequence, does the $\phi$ ratio come into play?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binary

I have recently been working on binary sequences trying to understand how often a $0$ or $1$ repeats in the following digit, i used a random generator and wrote down the number of patterns inside the sequence, for example$ "0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0"$ would give me a secondary set of numbers$ "1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 1"$ i then divided to find the mean and discovered (i think) that the longer the initial sequence, the closer to the phi ratio the final result will be. For the sequence above the found mean is $12/9 = 1.333$ 
I have limited knowledge of complex number theory and would love an explanation of whether this is an accurate observation and if so, why. Thanks

Comment: If I have understood the question, you are asking for the mean length of a run, yes?  But to get a run of length $1$ you need the second to differ from the first (probability $\frac 12$), to get length $2$ you need something like $XXY$, so $\frac 14$, and so on.  Thus the probability of a run of length $n$ is $\frac 1{2^n}$ so you want $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac n{2^n}=2$.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, you answered part so again ty, but im not quite clear on the finish, does that mean that 2 is the average sequence length? I want to know the average length of all runs.

Comment: Yes, barring error (always possible) I just computed the mean length of a run.  It's $2$.